# How many symmetric and antisymmetric relations are there in a set of 4 elements?

Tags: symmetric-groups

the answer to the above is 15, but I can only get 12.
Say the set A = {1,2,3,4}

I can only get {(1,1), ..., (1,1,1), ..., (1,1,1,1)} which gives me 12.

Where is my reasoning faulty?

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about binary relations?  What does $\{(1,1)\dots(1,1,1)\dots(1,1,1,1)\}$ mean?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I'm speaking about binary relations. 
That means the amount of binary relations that I found. To expand them:
12 relations: {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (1,1,1), (2,2,2), ..., (4,4,4,4)}

Comment: A binary relation is a set of ordered pairs.  Triples like $(1,1,1)$ play no part.  Furthermore, you only list one set.  You need $15$ sets, although I think the correct answer should be $16$.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind 15 sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking along the right lines, but you're getting confused.  You are correct in that if the relation is both symmetric and anti-symmetric, the only pairs in the relation must be of the form $(a,a)$ with $a\in\{1,2,3,4\}$  However, triples and quadruples play no part; a binary relation is a set of ordered pairs.  So, the questions is how many different sets are there whose only elements are of the required form?

Here are some examples:
$$\{(1,1)\}\\\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$$

Can you find the others?  Although your source says $15$, the right answer is $16$.

Comment: Well:
Sets of 1 element (like {(1,1)}): 4
Sets of 2 elements I'd say 6, of 3 elements I'd say 4 and of 4 elements I'd say 1. The 16th can't be {}, can it? Thank you

Comment: @toyoda Yes, it can be the empty set, why not?  $\emptyset$ satisfies (vacuously) both the definitions of symmetry and antisymmetry.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. saulpatz, thank you for your help!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark.  That way, others see it has been disposed of.

Comment: Done! Thank you

Comment: @toyoda It was my pleasure.